# Can't Override or Plugin Magento\Quote\Model\Cart\ShippingMethodManagement

Tags: plugin, magento2.2.3

I must be not understanding something. When I try to override or extend via plugin the Magento\Quote\Model\Cart\ShippingMethodManagement class it just doesn't work. Here's my code:

frontend/di.xml

```
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
<type name="Magento\Quote\Model\ShippingMethodManagement">
    <plugin name="vnsShippingmethodmanagement" type="VNS\Shippingquote\Model\ShippingMethodManagement" sortOrder="1"/>
</type>
```

Model/ShippingMethodManagement.php

```
public function __construct(
    \Magento\Catalog\Api\ProductRepositoryInterface $productRepository
) {
    $this->productRepository = $productRepository;
}

private function afterGetShippingMethods(Quote $quote, $output)
{
    error_log('test');
}
```

Module is installed/enabled, cache cleared, genereated/ deleted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The method that you're trying to plug in is private.

```
private function getShippingMethods(Quote $quote, $address)
```

Private methods can not be intercepted via Magento 2 plugins.

As per documentation:

**Plugins can not be used on following:**

> Final methods
>
> Final classes
>
> Non-public methods
>
> Class methods (such as static methods)
>
> __construct
>
> Virtual types
>
> Objects that are instantiated before Magento\Framework\Interception is bootstrapped

In your case the solution is to trace down the first public method that uses the "getShippingMethod" for your specific application and plugin into that.

Reference: https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/extension-dev-guide/plugins.html

Comment: Thanks for this, is that why I can't override it as well? I've tried both.

Comment: You can override full classes and have your own private methods, there is not limitation for this. However, you should avoid doing this at all costs as doing this would potentially break your application/shop with future Magento updates or 3rd party extensions. Try finding a public method that uses the "getShippingMethods" and plugin into it.

Comment: Thank you, that makes sense. I was able to get this working by doing an override and basically copying the entire ShippingMethodManagement.php from the core to my module and adding what I needed. Thanks again!